# Configure Virtual Box VMs to use separate Physical NIC on host machine

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I would like to configure about two to three Virtual Box vms, and each VM I want it to use separate Physical network adapter (cellular wireless usbs plugged to the host machine). Is this possible on a windows machine, if so how can I do this, any blog post or some steps to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you configure them as bridged adapters, you can just pick the physical adapter it hooks onto in the configuration. VirtualBox documentation Chapter 6, Bridged Networking.

Comment: Bridged setup might work, but be noted that WiFi client is not designed to support that. USB passthrough might be a better alternative, especially if you are looking to do WiFi-specific stuff from within the VMs.

Comment: The typical way I do this is USB Passthrough and install the NIC passed through in the VM